# Append 0 to all integer in string in given format

Tags: java, string

I need to convet
8.1.8 to 08.01.08
8.1.14 to 08.01.14

I want to achieve it without using string methods like split or indexof or tokenizer.
Some single line solution like string formatter.

Any suggestion or help.

This works for single integar
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt("2")));

but not able to apply to my pattern.

Comment: `String.format()` is a string method.

Comment: I know. I am looking for single line solution. Other string method solution will take several lines of code.

Comment: You can use `split()` in a single line too: `Arrays.stream(str.split("\\.")).map(s -> String.format(...)).collect(joining(","))`

Comment: thanks @shmosel Here is   System.out.println(Arrays.stream(version1.split("\\.")).map(s -> String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s))).collect(Collectors.joining(".")));
  System.out.println(Arrays.stream(version2.split("\\.")).map(s -> (s.length() <2) ? String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s)): s).collect(Collectors.joining(".")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

There is probably a shorter version of the below, nonetheless it gets the job done.

```java
String str = // your number, e.g. 8.1.8
str.replaceAll("^(\\d)\\.", "0$1.")
   .replaceAll("\\.(\\d)\\.", ".0$1.")
   .replaceAll("\\.(\\d)$", ".0$1")
```

The first `replaceAll` replaces a single digit followed by a dot at the beginning of `str` with that same digit preceded by a single 0 (zero).

The second `replaceAll` works on the string returned by the first `replaceAll` and replaces any single digit, between two dots, with that digit, again preceded by a single 0.

The last `replaceAll` replaces a single digit, preceded by a dot, at the end of the string.

If `str` is *8.1.8* then the result is *08.01.08*.

If `str` is *8.1.14* then the result is *08.01.14*

Comment: Thank you @Abra. It will work. Alternate is suggested by shmosel System.out.println(Arrays.stream(version1.split("\\.")).map(s -> String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s))).collect(Collectors.joining(".")));
  System.out.println(Arrays.stream(version2.split("\\.")).map(s -> (s.length() <2) ? String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s)): s).collect(Collectors.joining(".")));